# What should I do when I receive downvotes for a question?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have seen many questions on Stack Overflow with downvotes. If I receive too many downvotes, what should I do?

Should I remove the question?

Comment: good question .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should always try to improve the question if possible.

Deleted, downvoted questions count strong towards a question ban. If you ask a question stay put to answer comments and improve the question according to the comments.

Answer (score 6):

Think about *why* you've got downvotes.  Is it because of a lack of effort, unclear question, or is it because someone simply doesn't like you and has scoured your profile for posts to downvote?  In each case, there is something different you'd have to do to avoid further downvoting.  For example, if you've placed a lack of effort, add the relevant code or attempts to solve the problem.  Explain why what you think would be obvious doesn't work, and ask what to do in that situation.  If there is something odd that seems to be something to do with how it's specified, post the relevant sections of the specification.

If it really *is* unsalvageable to the point that it would be a good, objective question, then it would be wise to delete it if there isn't any good content on there worth keeping.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you will have a few comments about why people have down-voted you. They will clarify what is wrong with your question. But if you do not read the section [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), then you may not receive any comments since this community expects you to read that section and know how to ask a question in here. Basically people want your question to fit some basic rules:

- *Read how to ask section*: Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section
- *Tried to search before ask*: simply, here is not google. You will get downvotes for simple questions that can be easily find with a simple google search.
- *Read how to ask section*: Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section
- *No search effort in SO*: Here, we have a ~6 million Question and ~11 million answers to those questions. Making a simple search in here may direct you to a result that will help you solve your problem.
- *Read how to ask section*: Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section
- *We do not be psychic for you*: Your question must be clear, we are not psychic and we can neither see through your eyes nor read your mind. Explain your problem widely and with examples of code that cause your problem. If you ask `My code do not print what I want?` then you will get some comments like `Call a mechanics to fix it` and a few bonus down-votes.
- *Read how to ask section*: Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section
- *Do not try to make us do your job for you*: Simple enough, I guess
- *Read how to ask section*: Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section

If you do all above and it fits them but still you receive down-votes and there is no comments explaining them, ask why your question is being down-voted. There is no need to be panic or try to delete your question quickly. After you get answer, probably you will learn how to fix it.